# Php, how to cast/convert Exception to RuntimeException?

Tags: php, exception

there is a code snippet:

```
function test()
{
    if (mt_rand(1,4) === 2)
    {
        throw new \Exception('exception');
    }
}

try
{
    test();
}
catch(\Exception $e)
{
    //throw $e;
    throw new \RuntimeException($e->getMessage());
}
```

this is trivial example of course, but I there is a `test()` function which is used in two project. One of them it may throw an exception and is handled. But in another I must not handle it but let it happen and I can handle the stack.

But if I use the `throw new \RuntimeException($e->getMessage());` form, I wont get the true stack trace, I wont know if that happened in `test()` function.

But if I use the `throw $e;` form, its an `\Exception` but not a `RuntimeException`.

Normally an Exception is a usual exception which must be caught. But RuntimeException must not be caught since it can be resolved in code. So how to make that exception to RuntimeException?

Comment: `throw new \RuntimeException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);`

Comment: [But you cannot](https://3v4l.org/9IRlB) catch Exception without catching a RuntimeException. What gives?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remember that [RuntimeException](https://www.php.net/RuntimeException) has a `$previous` argument available in its [constructor](https://www.php.net/manual/en/exception.construct.php) where you can supply the original exception:

```
try {
    test();
} catch (\Exception $e) {
    throw new \RuntimeException($e->getMessage(), $e->getCode(), $e);
}
```

You can also omit the code, or even the message, should you not need it:

```
throw new \RuntimeException($e->getMessage(), previous: $e);
throw new \RuntimeException(previous: $e);
```

The stack trace can be retrieved from [.getTrace()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/throwable.gettrace.php) or [.getTraceAsString()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/throwable.gettraceasstring.php), depending on the format wanted, and previous exception is available through its [getter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/throwable.getprevious.php), so you can get the whole history with:

```
try {
    // ....
} catch (\RuntimeException $e) {
    echo 'Exception caught', PHP_EOL;
    while ($e) {
        echo 'Trace for ', get_class($e), "\n";
        print_r($e->getTrace());
        $e = $e->getPrevious();
    }
}
```

[Demo](https://3v4l.org/vDt7v#v8.2.3)

Comment: it still swallows the traceroute. The traceroute still begins from "throw new Runtimeerror" not from "throw new Exception"

Comment: Sorry, I cannot reproduce it: https://3v4l.org/t8bvq#v8.2.3

Comment: omg sorry, I forgot. I was using "debug_backtrace();" to print the backtrace

Comment: I've added an example to get stack trace, but if you edit the question and explain where you're using `debug_backtrace()`, I can have a look.

Comment: yes, yes, those exception traces had to be chained.